# Velocity & Momentum - I can't go the distance

Tags: c++, for-loop, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am currently working on an assignment that requires me to compile and executie a program with the following parameters:

Write a program that does the following: Calculates the Velocity and Momentum of an object. The formula for the velocity is V=d/t and the formula for Momentum is m=mass*velocity. Your program should consist of two functions: Passing By Values (one), One Passing By Pointers (one). It should also have a for loop and necessary print statements to print the result in a tabular format.
· The Passing By Values function is to calculate the velocity of the object, where you pass two parameters to this function a constant distance, but the time is the value of the for loop: I=1:

double Velocity(double distance,int time);
· The Pass By Pointers function calculates the momentum of the object, where you pass two parameters to this function: The Velocity and a constant mass of an object: mass=100:

double Momentum(double *Velocity,double *mass);

The output should have a tabular format consisting of Time, Velocity, and Momentum. There is no need for a user to enter a value, and the time input should range from 1-200.

** Now here is my struggle, I have put together as much as I can but can't seem to have it compile properly , it just keeps going to "Press any button to continue..."

I truly on't understand what I am doing wrong and just need help to compile and run, any help at all would be appreciated .

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

//Function prototypes (declaring the functions).
double velocity(double distance, int time);
double momentum(double *velocity ,double *mass);

//Main function.
int main()
{
    double PrimaryVelo(0);
    double TotalMomentum(0);
    int t(1);
    for (double d = 1; d <= 10; d++)
    {
        PrimaryVelo = velocity(d, t);
    }  //End for the primary for loop. 
    system("pause"); //Prevents closing of debug automatically.
    return 0;
} //End of the main function.

//Pass-by-value method for velocity.
double velocity(double distance, int time)
{
    return distance / time;
}

//Pass-by-pointers method for momentum.
double momentum(double &velocity ,double &mass)
{
    return (velocity * 205);
}
```

Comment: You say: "*it just keeps going to "Press any button to continue..."*" Well, of course. That's from `system("pause");` Your program compiles just fine, but that message is its only side effect. All the rest is some arithmetic which result you don't use and the compiler is optimizing it away.

Comment: Where is the code that is supposed to actually write any output?

Comment: `It should also have a for loop and necessary print statements to print the result in a tabular format.` Like already pointed out, you haven't fulfilled this requirement.

Comment: ::smacks self in forehead:: I am such an idiot.

Comment: @remyable i thought  for (double d = 1; d <= 10; d++) was the "for loop" ? Sorry for being such a noob :(

Comment: Yes, that's a for loop, but it doesn't contain any "print statements".  See this tutorial if you don't know how to write to the console: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Answer (score -1):

Well....
Here's your code.....

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double velocity(double distance, int time);
double momentum(double velocity ,double mass);

int main()
{
    double Mass=205;
    double Distance=100;
    double Velocity;
    //cout << "Time\t\tVelocity\tMomentum" << endl; //You'll need to reformat this
    for ( int Time = 1 ; Time <= 200 ; Time++ )
    {
        cout << Time << "\t" ;
        cout << velocity ( Distance , Time ) << "\t" ;
        Velocity = velocity ( Distance , Time ) ;
        cout << momentum ( Velocity , Mass ) << endl ;
    }

    // If you can't use conio.h and getch();
    // Use something like this to stop console from closing itself
    int a;  
    cin>>a;  
    return 0;
}
double velocity(double distance, int time)
{
    return distance / time;
}

double momentum(double velocity ,double mass)
{
    return velocity * mass;
}
```

Note : I've given you code with functions accepting arguments passed by values......

I hope it helps....

Have a nice day....